# Layout Image vertically centered / Text / Radiobuttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a litte problem to align my layout to an image (vertically centered), and text aligned with radiobuttons. I don't know how to.

The target is as follows:

[image]

My acutal result is as shown here:

[image]

Code of my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="11"
        android:columnCount="12"
        android:background="@color/colorWhiteActivityBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/mmg8"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="11"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/img_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_height"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/mmg_ja"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/mmg_nein"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mmg_statement_8_2"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_6"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView35"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_7"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView31"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_8"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView32"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_9"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView33"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/desc_padding"
            android:text="@string/mmg_statement_8_10"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/slide_desc"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </RadioGroup>

    </GridLayout>
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
tigercode

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your imageView,

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: I'm going to try this at home, but won't solve my problem concerning the radiobuttons...